# NullPointerException on addFooterView() on some devices

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception, footer

First, let me explain my code:
When the user clicks a button, this code is executed:

```
mMyListView.removeFooterView(mMyFooterView);
mMyListView.setAdapter(null);
//Fetch some data in an AsyncTask
```

When the Async has finished, this code is executed:

```
if (mMyList.size() > 0){
    mMyListView.addFooterView(mMyFooterView);
}    
MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(this, mMyList);
mMyListView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
```

This is where things go wrong though. Because on some devices I'm getting a NullPointerException on this line:

```
mMyListView.addFooterView(mMyFooterView);
```

Here's the StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:778)
at android.widget.ListView.addFooterView(ListView.java:387)
at android.widget.ListView.addFooterView(ListView.java:402)
at com.augustinianum.augustinianum.ManualCheckActivity.showScheduleChanges(ManualCheckActivity.java:84)
at com.augustinianum.augustinianum.ManualCheckActivity.access$1(ManualCheckActivity.java:81)
at com.augustinianum.augustinianum.ManualCheckActivity$CheckScheduleChange.onPostExecute(ManualCheckActivity.java:192)
at com.augustinianum.augustinianum.ManualCheckActivity$CheckScheduleChange.onPostExecute(ManualCheckActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The weird thing is that I only get this exception when the user clicks the button that fetches the data the second time. The first time everything goes smooth: the listView is shown and the footer is added. The second time though, I get this exception on some devices.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have declared mMyListView globally and initialize it onCreate..?

Comment: @Pragnani Yes, I defined it in my class block and filled it in onCreate() using findViewById().

Comment: It is hard to trace the problem with the following details, it will be helpful if you add some code.

Comment: @Pragnani Well, my code is pretty long so I don't think it's a good idea to paste my whole code here. If you need an extra section of my code just ask.

Comment: use pastebin and paste your code in it

Comment: What is your minimum API? The problem is mostly in the source code, but I need to know which version. Quite simply ListView is trying to add the footer to a `null` adapter, but you cannot call `addFooterView()` after calling `setAdapter()`...

Comment: @Sam Minimum API-level is 3. The device it crashes on runs Android 2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (mMyList.size() > 0){
    mMyListView.addFooterView(mMyFooterView);
}
```

It appears that you want to remove the footer when there is no data.  While I don't know how to prevent this error with your current code, I recommend a different tactic.

- If both data sets will use a footer then don't remove it to add it again (you can still change it if you want different content.)
- When the data set is empty hide the entire ListView with `setVisibilty(View.GONE)`.

But the error log and source code are clear, calling `setAdapter(null)` doesn't unregister the internal DataSetOberver which throws the NPE in GingerBread:

```
at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:778)
at android.widget.ListView.addFooterView(ListView.java:387)
```

Comment: But if I'd call addFooterView() when the footer is already there, won't it throw an exception as well?

Comment: I made a couple assumptions, before I clarify my idea... I waant to make sure it applies to what you want. Will your ListView always have a footer unless it is empty?

Comment: Do you ever change `mMyFooterView`'s layout or content?

Comment: Ok, rather than adding and removing your Footer when you change Adapters, instead add it once and when the Adapter is empty call `mMyListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`.  Later when you add data to `mMyList` make `mMyListView` visible again and the footer is already there.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for you great help!! I'm going to try this out and mark your answer as accepted as soon as I get it working! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I solved it:

When the user clicks the button, this code is executed:

```
mMyListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//Fetch some data in an AsyncTask
```

When the Async has finished, this code is executed:

```
mMyListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
if (mMyList.size() > 0){
    mMyListView.removeFooterView(mMyFooterView);
    mMyListView.addFooterView(mMyFooterView);
}    
MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(this, mMyList);
mMyListView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
```

This code works perfectly.

I'm going to accept Sam's answer though, because he explains well why the exception is thrown. Additionally, thanks to him, I could make up this solution. So +1 for Sam! :)

Comment: I'm surprised `mMyListView` allows you to add a footer after setting an Adapter, but I'm glad you found a solution!

Comment: @Sam I did some research on that and it appears that you are allowed to call `addHeaderView()`/`addFooterView()` after `setAdapter()` as long as you call one of those methods at least once before. Good to know I think!